# Setting ForeColor of DataRow in GridView ASP.NET (Not bounded to DataSource)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, colors, cells

I changed the first row cells color, but i don't want the second row (Number of Alloted Beds) to be affected. May i know how can i do that?

```
protected void bedStatsClass_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1];

            int number = int.Parse(cell.Text);

            if (number <= 10)
            {
                cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
            }
            else if (number > 10)
            {
                cell.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
                cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
            }

            //So on and so forth..
        }
    }
```

Image to Illustrate

[image]

Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: You want an odd-even behaviour?

Comment: What is your criteria to skip the second row? Or is it always the first / third row etc?

Comment: No.. Just the color of the cells in the first row (Number of Available Beds) to be changed according to the conditions. As for the second row (Number of Alloted Beds), will stay as the css styling has set the fore color to be. @VDWWD

Comment: And there's no criteria for the second row.. Just the forecolor of each cell in the second row to be as default..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RowIndex to check the row number. You can then color the element based on that number.

```
protected void bedStats_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            //do stuff with the first row
        }
        if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
        {
            //if you want to do something to rows 1, 3, 5 etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh i see.. may i ask do i need to add any codes for the counter to be incremented based on the any events? to specify which row should i add the color to and which row should i not? though with the code provided the logic on odd and even is there. @VDWWD

Comment: You're welcome. I've simplified the answer even more. I forgot for a moment that there is a RowIndex.

Answer (score 2):

There is complete solution for data row i.e. lable of grid view but not in the databound to datasource and we can use direclty without OnRowDataBound. plese try this best solution.so we have an example that is

#### In aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewBalance" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            DataKeyNames="card_no"  GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-striped"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewBalance_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="50" AllowPaging="True"
                             CellSpacing="4">                           
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="card_no" HeaderText="Card No" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="acc_no" HeaderText="Account No" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cname" HeaderText="Name" />                         
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="mobileno" HeaderText="Mobile No" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="balance" HeaderText="Balance" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="created_date" HeaderText="Creation date" DataFormatString="{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />                            
                              
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active-Status">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" ForeColor="White"  Text='<%# GetStatus(Eval("is_active").ToString()) %>' BackColor='<%# GetColor(Eval("is_active").ToString()) %>' ToolTip="Transaction Status"></asp:Label>
                                           
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            
                        </asp:GridView>
```

#### Code Behind:

```
This is used for the color of the grid view data rows.

   public System.Drawing.Color GetColor(string butColor)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color cr = new System.Drawing.Color();
            if (butColor == "1")
            {
                cr = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else if (butColor == "0")
            {
                cr = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            return cr;
        }

 This is used for the status:

   protected string GetStatus(string butStatus)
        {
            if (butStatus == "1")
            {
                butStatus = "ACTIVE";
            }
            else if (butStatus == "0")
            {
                butStatus = "DEACTIVE";
            }
            return butStatus;
        }
```